# Box2D Libgdx block based platformer

Tags: libgdx, box2d

How can I create a physics based world from blocks for a platformer, so that the players moving on the block don't get stuck? I think that those who have used box2D know that when you try to move on ground made from polygon shapes (squares) you usually get stuck sometimes around the corners. Is there anyway to solve this issue? I thought they would fix it with some updates but it seems it's still happening... This is a link to the problem I have encountered: [ghost vertices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oP7ZLeyc9HU). Normally you would use a single line (chain shape), but I need the terrain to be made of blocks so some portions can fall or be moved.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem now? The youtube link you've posted has a link to the article about this problem in the decription. http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices